# compute the average of rows with float numbers

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to compute the average of rows (only the columns of number value, in this case they are column 1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15)
I tried:

```
df['avg'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

It does not generate the values of column 'avg' tho
anyone has idea to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because some columns are not number, you can use

```py
df['avg'] = df[[1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15]].mean(axis=1)
```

Or use [pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

```py
df['avg'] = df.select_dtypes(include=['float64']).mean(axis=1)
```